# How does one get the prompt (>) in the Edwin editor for MIT/GNU Scheme?

Tags: scheme, edwin

Nomally, you will get a prompt like this:

```
=>
```

where you can type in expressions for evaluation:

```
=> (+ 3 4)
7
```

But with Edwin, there is only a blinking black rectangle and nothing happens when you type in expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: In this manual:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user.pdf

section 7.5, it says:

> When Edwin starts, it has one
>   buffer: a REPL buffer called
>   ‘*scheme*’. The command `M-x repl`
>   selects this buffer, if it exists;
>   otherwise it creates a new REPL
>   buffer. If you want two REPL buffers,
>   just rename the ‘*scheme*’ buffer to
>   something else and run `M-x repl` again.

You can use the following also (see section 7.4 from the manual):

- C-x C-e - evaluate s-exp before the cursor
- M-z - evaluate the whole definition containing the cursor
- M-: - evaluate from mini-buffer
- C-M-z - evaluate the whole region
- M-o - evaluate the whole buffer

(C stands for Ctrl, M for Alt on PC keyboards).

Never used it, but from this:

- http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall99/ai/scheme/scheme.html

you should be able to get the prompt by `M-x run-scheme` (`M-x` stand for `Alt-X` on today's keyboards).

Comment: Thanks, but I typed `ALT-x run-scheme` and got back `[No match]`.

Comment: After typing the expression, I type `CTRL-x` and then `CTRL-e`. The result appears on the next line, preceded by `;Value:`.

Comment: Yes, that's the evaluate function - it actually evaluates the while s-expression before. You can also use `M-:` to input it in a mini buffer - all in section 7.4, take a look at it.

Answer (score 14):

After installing and running the `MIT-GNU Scheme` from the Start menu, you get two windows, `Edwin *scheme*` and `MIT/GNU Scheme`. Go to the second window and press `Ctrl+U`. You should get the `1 ]=>` prompt right away.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe" --library "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib" --edit`
starts Edwin, whereas
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe" --library "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib"`
gives you a repl prompt